# Does ruby 1.9.1 still have problems dealing with non-ASCII charcters in rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just upgraded from MRI-1.8.7 to MRI-1.9.1 and heard about this [lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2188-i18n-fails-with-multibyte-strings-in-ruby-19-similar-to-2038) which indicates that Ruby 1.9.1 and Rails 2.3.x won't play nicely together when a user enters any kind of non-ASCII standard character (i.e. å é Ã Ø å ल) unless rails is patched.

My problem is that I CAN'T reproduce the bug.

I've tried everything.  I've entered every single character I can into my db and the app stays cool.

But because the ticket is still open I'm wondering whether or not I should be concerned about this issue.

So can anyone tell me what conditions must exist in order for this issue to arise?  Should I be worried about it?  Are there any other Ruby 1.9.1 users who know anything about this?

FWIW:  App runs on Heroku, Ruby 1.9.1, gems 1.3.6, rails 2.3.5 and Postgrs.  I don't use Il8n in any way.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything will have bugs.

If you have not been able to reproduce this issue with your current app, chances are your users will not be able to either. But because Rails is open-source, if you run into the bug, you can look at the stacktrace, dive into the code. You can even s/submit a patch/fork and submit a pull request/ to the core team.

Comment: thanks, after 6 weeks of using 1.9.1, I have not run into any significant problems so I think I can close this question.